# How to open Modelsim project files

Tags: modelsim

I can open Modelsim project files by doing File->Recent Projects. However I do not know any other way to open projects. If I use File->Open it only opens up individual files, not projects. How can projects be opened?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

File=> Open,
In the Open File dialog box, select **Project Files (*.ini, *.mpf)** in the **Files of Type** pull‐down, select the project and click Open.